# Convert list from dataframe into numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am accessing some vectors stored as `arrays` in Google BigQuery, using the python client:

`df = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()`

The resulting `dataframe` has a single column which looks like the following:

```
    page_vector
0   [0.11585406959056854, 0.4495273232460022, -0.0...
1   [0.3589635491371155, 0.529633104801178, 0.3646...
2   [0.05760370194911957, 0.10355205088853836, 0.7...
3   [0.12493933737277985, 0.7082784175872803, 0.26...
4   [-0.660869300365448, -0.5055545568466187, -0.2...
```

Now I would like to do various calculations on these vector values such as calculation of the mean, cosine similarity etc..

My issue is that the values are stored as an array of lists ( I believe) and I am not able to convert them into regular `numpy` arrays.

```
df.values

array([[list([0.11585406959056854, 0.4495273232460022, -0.06741087883710861, 0.009115549735724926, 0.03358231857419014, 0.3813880980014801, 0.5367750525474548, 0.1125958263874054, -0.04873140528798103, -0.15494178235530853])],
       [list([0.3589635491371155, 0.529633104801178, 0.3646768629550934, -0.5236702561378479, -0.20803043246269226, -0.40205657482147217, 0.9097139835357666, 0.3311547636985779, -0.10366004705429077, -0.31620144844055176])],
       [list([0.05760370194911957, 0.10355205088853836, 0.7606179118156433, -0.40389031171798706, -0.4287498891353607, -0.5946164727210999, 1.470175862312317, 0.12346278876066208, -0.13954032957553864, -0.4611101448535919])],
       [list([0.12493933737277985, 0.7082784175872803, 0.26176416873931885, 0.04834984615445137, -0.1890079379081726, -0.2270711362361908, 0.8319875597953796, 0.39853358268737793, -0.11916585266590118, -0.5312120318412781])],
       [list([-0.660869300365448, -0.5055545568466187, -0.260611891746521, 0.6198488473892212, 0.07465806603431702, 0.6059150099754333, -0.548044741153717, 0.38490045070648193, -0.49995312094688416, 0.1975364089012146])]],
      dtype=object)
```

How should I manipulate the results from BigQuery into something I can then use for various calculations?

I have tried many avenues such as :
`df.apply(lambda x: np.asarray(x, dtype=float))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `df` `info` or `dtypes`.  That column is `object` dtype.

`df.values` produces a 2d array, in this case (n,1) shape, rows by columns.

`df.values[:,0]` should be a (n,) shape array.  You could also select the column before using `values`.  `Series.values` produces a 1d array (still object dtype).

`np.stack(df.values[:,0])` should produce a 2d array, provided the lists are all the same size.  This concatenates the lists row by row.

And do compare this with the `tolist` approach.  Look at the resulting list of lists.

Look at `pandas` documentation you'll see that while `Series` has a `tolist` method, `DataFrame` does not.

```
In [60]: df1                                                                    
Out[60]: 
           1
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [2, 3, 4]
2  [3, 4, 5]

In [62]: df1.values                                                             
Out[62]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3])],
       [list([2, 3, 4])],
       [list([3, 4, 5])]], dtype=object)

In [63]: df1.values.shape                                                       
Out[63]: (3, 1)

In [64]: df1.values[:,0]                                                        
Out[64]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([2, 3, 4]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
In [65]: np.stack(df1.values[:,0])                                              
Out[65]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

`tolist` doesn't work for the dataframe, just for a Series:

```
In [69]: df1.tolist()                                                           
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

In [70]: df1[1].tolist()                                                        
Out[70]: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

`values` from the `Series`:

```
In [72]: df1[1].values                                                          
Out[72]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([2, 3, 4]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj would you recommend converting them in situ or into a new col in the `df`?

Comment: I don't follow.  That column is object dtype with one list per row.  You could replace each list with an equivalent 1d array.  But that still doesn't give a 2d array.  You could make a new dataframe from the 2d array, one df column per column of the array.

Comment: I would like to operate within the df if possible, as there are other columns which describe the data.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `list` first then make it to `numpy` array

```
np.array(df.page_vector.tolist())
```

Comment: This is great thanks, could you add a little more explanation for other who are reading this? Also is it possible to do this on the df itself?